# Pyspark custom receivers to read mongo change stream logs using spark streaming

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to use spark streaming to read data from mongodb change streams[Link at the end].

Here want to collect 30 sec dump and then push into some file.
I understand that I might have to write some custom receivers (using pyspark) to receive data from the concerned data source but I could not find any document which discuss about custom receiver for Spark Streaming using PYTHON.

Below document link as well mentions of using java or scala.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html

I am using simple python code to read data from ChangeStreams but it does not fulfilling my requirement.

Note : In below code iterating over the `change_stream` one by one using for loop( Instead want to read documents coming within 30 sec timeframe in bulk and then write it to some destination file)

```
import os
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps
STREAM_DB="mongodb://<username>:<pwd>@<host>:<port>/<database to be used> authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(STREAM_DB)
change_stream = client.<database name>.watch()
print(change_stream) 
f = open("<filename>", "a")
for change in change_stream:
    f.write(dumps(change) + '\n')
f.close()
```

I do not see any document which discuss about custom receiver for Spark Streaming using PYTHON.
Below document link as well mentions of using java or scala.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html

Is there a way I can read streaming mongodb change stream data using spark.

[1] : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: Can anyone help if they have across such scenario

Comment: The solution which worked for us is in 2 steps instead of directly trying to get it through Spark.
1) Sending the Mongo change stream data to Google Cloud PubSub using python standalone script which runs as a service.
2) Wrote custom receiver in java and accessed it using pyspark (Spark Streaming code)

This github link has custom receiver code specifically for Spark-PubSub
Link : https://github.com/SignifAi/Spark-PubSub

Comment: The MongoDB Spark Connector now supports Spark Structured Streaming.  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/structured-streaming/#configuring-a-read-stream-from-mongodb.


streamingDataFrame = (<local SparkSession>.readStream
  .format("mongodb")
  .load()
)

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for us is present in comment section